# Do the EDAR sinodont mutation affect brain size or intelligence?

Tags: mutations, human-evolution, intelligence

I am reading on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectodysplasin_A_receptor) that a certain mutation in the "Ectodysplasin A receptor" known as rs3827760 or 370A is responsible for the sinodont dentition pattern in East Asians as well as affecting breast size, causing thicker hair and "reduced chin protrusion".

**Question:** In what way, if any, does this mutation affect brain size and intelligence?

Does this mutation cause any other evolutionary advantages?

One would expect that humans have gone through a series of mutations affecting our skull, making it less robust and causing us to have weaker jaws than apes, but then making room for a larger and more well developed brain.